# Matlab: legend color for multiple scatter

Tags: matlab, legend, scatter

I have a problem, the colors of my legend correspond to the last color given in the last scatter. How I can have 3 different colors in my legends?

```
            scx1=s.nF(:,1:length(s.rvars1)); 
            scy1=s.rvars1(:,1:length(s.rvars1));
            scx2=s.nF(:,1:length(s.rvars2));
            scy2=s.rvars2(:,1:length(s.rvars2));
            scx3=s.nF(:,1:length(s.rvars3));
            scy3=s.rvars3(:,1:length(s.rvars3));
            hold on;
            col=hsv(3);
            p1=scatter(scx1, scy1,10,col(1,:),'fill');
            p2=scatter(scx2, scy2,10,col(2,:),'fill');
            p3=scatter(scx3, scy3,10,col(3,:),'fill');

            legend([p1 p2 p3],{'label1', 'label2', 'label3'});
```

Regards,

Ben

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get three entries with three different colors (those in `col`)